# Trying to understand the logic of an IF statement

Tags: c, snmp

I'm trying to construct some Ada code, but to do so, I have to understand some C.

In net-snmp-5.8.1.pre2/apps/snmpbulkwalk.c and probably others, there is an `if` statement which I am trying to understand what is happening and to separate it out, thus:

```
if ((vars->name_length < rootlen) || (memcmp(root, vars->name, rootlen * sizeof(oid))) != 0) {
   /*
    * not part of this subtree
    */
    running = 0;
    continue;
}
```

I get `name_length < rootlen`, I also get that `memcpy` always returns a pointer and never fails. From my poor eyesight it seems to say that if the `<` fails, it will then try the `memcpy` which always succeeds and then execute the  contents of the IF block. But no... If that were the case, you could just put the `memcpy` inside the block.

No matter how I separate out the `if` statement, I can never get it to work the way it is already coded.

Comment: `memcpy` or `memcmp`? One is in the code and other in your question, but they are different functions.

Comment: Good grief... I did mention my poor eyesight...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `if` does "short circuit" evaluation. It is basically of the form:

```
if (expression_A || expression_B)
    do_something;
```

It evaluates `expression_A`, if it is *true*, `expression_B` is *not* evaluated. And, the `if` is *taken* (i.e. `do_something` is executed)

If `expression_A` is *false*, then `expression_B` is evaluated. If *it* is *true*, the `if` is *taken*

Restating the actual `if` code:

```
if (vars->name_length < rootlen) {
   /*
    * not part of this subtree
    */
    running = 0;
    continue;
}

if (memcmp(root, vars->name, rootlen * sizeof(oid)) != 0) {
   /*
    * not part of this subtree
    */
    running = 0;
    continue;
}
```

Restating the general case:

```
if (expression_A)
    do_something;
else {
    if (expression_B)
        do_something;
}
```